# Regex exclude text between parenthesis from match

Tags: regex, go

given the following text:

```
{field1} == value1 && {field2} == value2  && ({field3} == value3 && {field4} == value4) && {field5} == value5
```

I'm trying to create a regex that match all the `&&` on that text but excluding the ones between parentheses (so the && between value3 and field4 should be ignored). I've been able to do it with the following regex: `(\&{2})(?![^\(]*\))` [this one works and it's doing what I need] but the problem is that I'm using Golang and doesn't support negative lookahead. There is any way to do it **without negative lookahead**? Parentheses can not be nested.

Basically I want to split by the `&&` but ignoring the ones between parentheses and get something like:

```
[&&, &&, &&]
[{field1} == value1, {field2} == value2, ({field3} == value3 && {field4} == value4), {field5} == value5]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with golang, but short of using a proper language parser you could do this with 3 regex: first replace all `&&` inside parenthesis with a placeholder char, then do the split on `&&`, then restore the `&&` in each array item from the placeholder char

Comment: Honestly it sounds like a good enough solution, I was too obfuscated to do it with the regex and missed something so easy as that, I'm pretty sure it will do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: nop, no nested parentheses

Comment: Thanks, edited the question to clarify that and added what I'm expecting

Comment: Keep in mind that `["&&", "&&", "&&"]` is equivalent to simply providing a count of the number of matches since the location of each match in the string is not being saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a technique by which everything that isn't wanted is matched, but not captured, and everything that is wanted is matched and captured (i.e., saved to a capture group). You can do that with the following regular expression.

```
\([^\]]*\)|(&&)
```

which reads, "match a string enclosed in parentheses or (`|`) match the string `"&&"` and save it to capture group 1". The idea is to (in code) disregard matches that are not captured.

For the following string the matches (denoted by `"m"`s) and captures (denoted by `"c"`s) are shown.

```
{f1} == v1 && {f2} == v2  && ({f3} == v3 && {f4} == v4) && {f5} == v5
           mm                mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mm
           cc                                           cc
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vTCivv/1)

At the beginning of the string (`{`) neither `\([^\]]*\)` nor `(&&)` are matched, so the string pointer is advanced by one character to `f`. Again, there is no match so the string pointer is advance one more character, to `1`. This continues (with no matches) until the first `&` is reached. `\([^\]]*\)` is not matched but `(&&)` is. We are interested in that match because it is captured (to capture group 1).

The string pointer is then moved one character ahead at a time, with no more matches found, until `(` is reached. At that point, `({f3} == v3 && {f4} == v4)` is matched by `\([^\]]*\)`, but since it is not captured we pay no attention to it. This continues until the end of the string is reached.

Alternatively, we could use the regular expression

```
\([^\]]*\)|&&
```

and examine the first character of each match. If it is `(` we discard the match from consideration.

When each match of `&&` is found we might (in code) replace it with another (possibly empty) string, obtain its offset into the string (for some purpose) or simply increment a counter of the number of matches in the string. This of course depends on why we want to match those strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Golang, but short of using a proper language parser you could do this with 3 regex:

1. replace all `&&` inside parenthesis with a placeholder char
2. split on `&&`
3. restore the `&&` in each array item from the placeholder char